# AWS Elastic Beanstalk cannot rebuild environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to recreate environment using "Recreate Environment" action but it fails due to the impossibility of deleting 3 security groups. I have tried to delete those security groups by hand. I couldn't do that either, because all 3 are associated with network interfaces.

When I try to delete any of those 3 network interfaces I get an error:

> Error deleting network interfaces You do not have permission to access
>   the specified resource.

I have all permissions, any idea how to delete those network interfaces? Or how to force elastic to recreate environment ignoring its errors? Thanks!

Comment: Are the security groups used by any services (e.g. RDS) that are not controlled by Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @Brian They are used only by Elastic Beanstalk (I've checked dependences). Example descriptions `Elastic Beanstalk created security group used when no ELB security groups are specified during ELB creation` and `Enable database access to Beanstalk application`. RDS for this security group has been removed by "Recreate Environment". Thanks!